# Is the Brent driver supported in OpenMDAO 1.x+?

Tags: openmdao

I am working on converting code that used the Brent driver to the new OpenMDAO 1.x+. However, I couldn't find the new version. Is the Brent driver supported in OpenMDAO 1.x+?. Would it be possible to request the Brent driver if it hasn't yet been converted to the new version?

Comment: do you want to use Brent across a single component of a group?

Answer (score 0):

We haven't migrated the Brent driver over yet. We can add it to the list of things to do, but I don't know how tough it will be. Brent is a special driver designed to handle only a single variable and im not 100% sure how we'll handle that situation now.

Comment: Okay. I would use it across a single component of a group. I will attempt to recreate it on my own, but any help from you guys would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to use it across a single component I suggest that u use an implicit component with an internal solver and provide partial derivatives of of the residuals along with the outputs.

That way you can converge the whole thing with the standard Brent driver and just let OpenMDAO compute the total derivatives around the converged point. A good example of this is our [LinearSystem](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/blob/master/openmdao/components/linear_system.py) component. It solves a simple linear system using numpy.linalg.solve. But it reports its behavior to the framework as an implicit component.